# rosbridge (dynamic_reconfigure function?)

Tags: rosbridge, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody ,

After few days trying to make rosbridge work, I finaly succeeded. Thank you to Tjay for his answers and his patience.
I want to develop several widget for the client more oriented javascript and html5 than ros.

I would like to know if a dynamic_reconfigure and a simple echo functions are available in the rosbridge API or should i create my_own services ?

Sincerely,

Benoît

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32126/rosbridge-(dynamic_reconfigure-function?)/) by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, we try to keep the services that rosbridge itself provides to a minimum (type discovery, etc.). That said, rosbridge should have no problem allowing you to use a simple ROS echo service. I'm not actually familiar with the underlying way in which dynamic_reconfigure clients work However, if they are "pure" (i.e. are implemented on top of topics and services instead of via linking), writing a Javascript client could be more involved but definitely be possible. Users have written actionlib clients in Javascript, for example.

If you're looking at using an echo service to help you debug, I've always found it helpful to use the rostopic command-line tools pub command. I just leave it publishing to a topic at a given rate.

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0